# ssrs interactive sorting

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Okay. two questions on interactive sorting:
1. How to sort on multiple columns without holding SHIFT key?(like this: http://lukehayler.com/2011/04/sorting-on-multiple-columns-in-ssrs/)
2. How do I cancel sorting? So, usually on most web, first click on sorting arrows icon sorts by ascending, second click sorts by descending, third click cancels sorting. With SSRS I only observe first two options. Is there a way to cancel column sorting?

Comment: #1 - That's just the way it works. It's built into the report viewer control. I suppose you could roll your own...

Comment: What does "cancel sorting" mean?  go back to the original order of when the report was first executed?

Comment: @iPolvo, yes, exactly. reset sorting.

Comment: @iPolvo, something they do here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/linq/defaultcs.aspx (if you click on a header multiple times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Right now that is just how the report viewer works, as others have said you could write your own controll to view the reports but this may not be an option due to time or skill level constraints.

Other people have written their own custom report viewer controls however I have always stuck to the MS version so I havent got much experience with these, and I would suspect any good ones would be a paid solution.

2) I would love this option myself, again you cant reset the sorting in this way as SSRS does not keep a record of the initial 'unordered' state of the data.

The only options you really have here are to reload your data with its original parameters or as nathan pointed out include a column that contains the starting sort order, however users may not like this as it is adding data which is not really relevant to the report data.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no way to do this with the standard report viewer control

2) There is no way to "cancel" sorting. However assuming the data was sorted into some order originally then you could include a column on the report that represents the original sort order (if it's complex ordering then you could represent this with a sequence number). This would allow the user to sort on that column to return to the original order of the report.